# Stuck with lambda expression and Map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the `Person` class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Person {
    private String name;
    Map<String,Integer> Skills=new HashMap<>(); // skill name(String) and level(int)

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public Map<String,Integer> getSkills(){
        return this.Skills;
    }
}
```

And the `App` class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
import static java.util.Comparator.*;
public class App {
    private List<Person> people=new ArrayList<>(); // the people in the company

    public Map<String,Set<String>> PeoplePerSkill(){
        return this.people.stream().collect(groupingBy(p-> p.getSkills().keySet() //<-get  
                                                                           //^problem here
                                  ,mapping(Person::getName,toSet())));
    }
}
```

In the `App` class the `PeoplePerSkill` method need to return the `Set` of people names per skill. It means a skill could be owned by many people.

I stuck with the `groupingBy(p->p..........., )` I just can't get the `String` of skill's name, I tried so many ways but things get way stranger :(.

By the way, currently my code returns `Map<Object, Set<String>>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it via flat-mapping, though it probably doesn't look very beautiful:

```
public Map<String,Set<String>> PeoplePerSkill(){
    return this.people.stream()
        .<Entry<String, String>>flatMap(p -> 
            p.getSkills().keySet()
                .stream()
                .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(s, p.getName())))
        .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, mapping(Entry::getValue, toSet())));
}
```

Here `flatMap` creates a stream of pairs `(skill, person name)`, which are collected in the manner quite similar to yours. I'm using the `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` class to represent the pair, you may use something else.

Using my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library this task can be solved prettier:

```
return StreamEx.of(this.people)
        .mapToEntry(p -> p.getSkills().keySet(), Person::getName)
        .flatMapKeys(Set::stream)
        .grouping(toSet());
```

Internally it's almost the same, just syntactic sugar.

**Update:** seems that my original solution was wrong: it returned map `person_name -> [skills]`, but if I understand the OP correctly, he wants map `skill -> [person_names]`. The answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if streams would make your life easier here. IMO this code is much easier to read and cleaner.

```
public Map<String, Set<String>> peoplePerSkill() {

    Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (Person person : people) {
        for (String skill : person.getSkills().keySet()) {
            map.putIfAbsent(skill, new HashSet<>());
            map.get(skill).add(person.getName());
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

You can also "simplify"

```
map.putIfAbsent(skill, new HashSet<>());
map.get(skill).add(person.getName());
```

with

```
map.computeIfAbsent(skill, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(person.getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use external libraries in your code, you might want to consider using a [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) instead of a `Map<String, Set<String>>`. Unfortunately, a solution using a `Multimap` is going to require more boilerplate since it isn't officially supported by the JDK, but it should lead to a "cleaner" solution:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person larry = new Person("larry");
    larry.getSkills().put("programming", 0);
    larry.getSkills().put("cooking", 0);

    Person nishka = new Person("nishka");
    nishka.getSkills().put("programming", 0);
    nishka.getSkills().put("cooking", 0);

    Person mitul = new Person("mitul");
    mitul.getSkills().put("running", 0);
    mitul.getSkills().put("cooking", 0);

    Person rebecca = new Person("rebecca");
    rebecca.getSkills().put("running", 0);
    rebecca.getSkills().put("programming", 0);

    List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(larry, nishka, mitul, rebecca);

    Multimap<String, String> peopleBySkills = people.stream().collect(
        collectingAndThen(toMap(Person::getName, p -> p.getSkills().keySet()),
            CollectingMultimap.<String, String, Set<String>> toMultimap()
                .andThen(invert())));
    System.out.println(peopleBySkills);
  }

  private static <K, V, I extends Iterable<V>> Function<Map<K, I>, Multimap<K, V>> toMultimap() {
    return m -> {
      Multimap<K, V> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
      m.entrySet().forEach(e -> map.putAll(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
      return map;
    };
  }

  private static <K, V> Function<Multimap<K, V>, Multimap<V, K>> invert() {
    return m -> {
      return Multimaps.invertFrom(m, ArrayListMultimap.create());
    };
  }
```

---

```
{running=[mitul, rebecca], cooking=[nishka, larry, mitul], programming=[nishka, larry, rebecca]}
```

Notice how I had to supply the generic parameters to `toMultimap()`. Java 8 has much better generic inference, but it [does not infer chained method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19934204/758280).

You will either need to explicitly supply the generic parameters or declare a local variable `Function<Map<String, Set<String>>, Multimap<String, String>> toMultimap` in order for the compiler to correctly infer the type parameters.