# Why does a java set the type-argument to object when a lambda expression is passed that has the type as parameter- and return-type?

Tags: java, lambda, type-parameter

When a lambda expression is passed to a method it is possible to retrieve its return-type and the parameter-types (if specifically given by the caller) using type-parameters.

What I don't understand is that java seems to discard the type information given by the return-type of a lambda expression if the expression also uses the return-type as a parameter-type.

It is really hard to explain this question with words. Therefore I wrote the sample code below for further clarification.

```
//Case 1
@FunctionalInterface
interface Test<R> {
    void returnValue(R takes);
}

static <R> R test(Test<R> test) {
    //... Do something with test
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    test((a) -> System.out.println("called"));  
    //This call will always return an Object
    //This is clear. It is totally unnknow wich type a has at compile-time
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Case 2
@FunctionalInterface
interface Test<R> {
    R returnValue();
}

static <R> R test(Test<R> test) {
    //... Do something with test
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    test(() -> "  ");   
    //This call will always return a String
    //This is clear. R is specified to be a String by the return value.
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Case 3
@FunctionalInterface
interface Test<R> {
    R returnValue(R takes);
}

static <R> R test(Test<R> test) {
    //... Do something with test
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    test((a) -> "  ");  
    //This call will always return an Object
    //This it not clear. R is specified to be a String by the return value
    //Why doesn't it return a String ?
}
```

**Edit:**
Going deeper into the problem I noticed that the problem only really occurs when chaining calls. The code below demonstrates this. It was compiled in eclipse using java version 1.8.0_73.

```
package test;

public class TestLambdaGenerics {

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface Test<R> {
        R returnValue(R takes);
    }

    static <R> Test<R> test(final Test<R> test) {
        // ... Do something with test
        return test;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Test<String> t = test((a) -> "  ");
        // Above works fine
        final String t2 = test((a) -> "  ").returnValue("  ");
        // Above terminates with output:
        // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
        // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String
        //
        // at test.TestLambdaGenerics.main(TestLambdaGenerics.java:18)
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Question is resolved "chain-calling" with type-inference is just not supported by java at the moment.

See: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934204/java-8-and-generalized-target-type-inference) or [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/lesser-known-java-8-feature)

Comment: In case 3, `String b = test((a) -> "  ");` compiles without issue, so the type `String` is inferred. I don't understand your issue.

Comment: If you are getting compiler errors, can you tell us the version of java and compiler you are using?

Comment: I'm using the version 1.8.0_73 of java and I'm compiling with eclipse.
See the comment on @HopefullyHelpful s answer.

Comment: I think it's a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24798163/3973077

Answer (score 0):

I tested your examples and in case 2/3 the returnValue always has the class String.

```
/*
//Case 1
public class LambdaGenerics {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(test((a) -> System.out.println("called")).getClass());
        //This call will always return a Test<Object>
        //This is clear. It is totally unknown which type a has at compile-time
    }

    static <R> Test<R> test(Test<R> test) {
      //... Do something with test
        return test;
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface Test<R> {
  void returnValue(R takes);
}

*/
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
//Case 2
public class LambdaGenerics {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(test(() -> "test").returnValue().getClass());
        //This call will always return a Test<Object>
        //This is clear. It is totally unknown which type a has at compile-time
    }

    static <R> Test<R> test(Test<R> test) {
      //... Do something with test
        return test;
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface Test<R> {
  R returnValue();
}
*/


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
//Case 3
public class LambdaGenerics {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(test((a) -> "  ").returnValue(test((a) -> "  ")).getClass());
        //This call will always return a Test<Object>
        //This is clear. It is totally unknown which type a has at compile-time
    }

    static <R> Test<R> test(Test<R> test) {
      //... Do something with test
        return test;
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface Test<R> {
  R returnValue(R takes);
}
*/
```

Comment: Adding the following to your main-method:
final String t = test((a) -> "  ").returnValue(test((a) -> "  "));
Will yield the excpetion:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String

Comment: @SilentStorm Are you talking about case 3 here?

Comment: @PaulBoddington Yes indeed.

Comment: @SilentStorm In that case I'm a bit confused about what `String t = test((a) -> " ").returnValue(test((a) -> " "));` is supposed to mean. `test((a) -> " ")` is a `Test<String>`, so the method `returnValue` requires a `String`. However you are passing `test((a) -> " ")`, which is a `Test<String>`, not a `String`. If I write `String t = Main.test((a) -> " ").returnValue("");` I get compilation problems which I can solve by doing this: `String t = Main.<String>test((a) -> " ").returnValue("");`. I think the compilation issue here is by design, not a bug. I'll try to find explanation on SO.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I updated the question to contain a better example. There you can see, that the problem only happens when chaining.